# Is transform.forward mutable?

Tags: c#, unity

Suppose I have a `GameObject`, and I want it's `transform.forward` to be facing up. Is it possible to change it as seen below?

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
        forward = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
        transform.forward = forward;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
transform.forward = transform.up;
```